# Disable feign encoding of PathVariables

Tags: java, spring, encoding, spring-cloud-feign, path-variables

I have the following Feign Client:

```
public interface MyServiceClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/item/{itemKey}")
    Item getItem (@PathVariable("itemKey") String itemKey);
}
```

The items can contains special characters like `:` or `::` which are being encoded.

Request URL becomes something like:

- `https://myservice.com/item/a%3Ab%3A%3Ac`

Rather than:

- `https://myservice.com/item/a:b::c`

Can anyone help me understand how can we fix this issue?

Comment: The encoding and decoding happens automatically. You don't have to do anything to decode the path variables or request parameters unless you use a custom encoding scheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenFeign has an issue tracking:

- https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/1190

Guess it will be implemented by `spring-cloud-feign` once its done.
Meanwhile, my workaround for this issue is to create a `RequestInterceptor` and replace `%3A` with `:`

```
public class MyRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        template.uri(template.path().replaceAll("%3A", ":"));
    }
}
```

And use this `requestInterceptor` to build your `feignClient` in the `feignConfig`:

```
@Bean
public Feign.Builder tcsClientBuilder() {
    return Feign.builder().requestInterceptor(new MyRequestInterceptor());
}
```

Comment: Is there a way we can stop encoding @RequestParam ? | is converted to %7C. This is causing a problem

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in my case:

```
//ICustomFeignClient =  your Feign client interface
Feign.builder()
    .client(new OkHttpClient())
    .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
    .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
    .logger(new Slf4jLogger(builderClass))
    .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
    .requestInterceptor(new CustomFeignRequestInterceptor())
    .target(ICustomFeignClient, baseUrl);
                
// custom interceptor class below 
class CustomFeignRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
               
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
    // you can replace the string you don't want from here
    requestTemplate.uri(
        requestTemplate.request()
            .url()
            .replaceAll("%3D", "=")
            .replaceAll("%26", "&")
        );
    }
}
```